# SSAS see data from Fact Table that HAS NOT been dimensioned

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, dimensional-modeling

my SSAS Cube works like a dream, however, I have one column in the Fact Table that is incoming telephone numbers (+64 etc etc), this has not been dimensioned as yet, but for the reporting layer (SSRS) I need to see this telephone number as part of the wider query - but cannot figure out how get to it.

I had hoped that I could make a new measure with "No Aggregations" but get the error message "The aggregate function None is not allowed in this edition of Analysis Services."  I am using a standard edition of SSAS.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to bring this forward for use, or do I just dimension it and be done with it?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be put in a dimension rather than in a fact. I'd suggest it should be made a 'member property' by then setting AttributeHierarchyEnabled = False, so it can be seen along with other dimensional properties when needed, but not used for hierarchies and the like.